# React componentDidMount not called on component reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of data table. In data table I have data w.r.t to some device Whenever I click ID I open a sidebar with some data displaying inside that.
The problem what I am facing is onclick of ID first time it calls the api gets the data and displays properly. But, after closing sidebar when I click again on ID it doesn't load anything (no calls for APIs).

I am not able to create code pen for that but below is my code.

My Code -

onCLick ID -

```
_onClickCompliance(deviceId);

const _onClickCompliance = deviceId => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <ComplianceDetails deviceId={deviceId} />,
        document.getElementById("ComplianceDetailsModalDiv")
    );
};
```

Inside ComplianceDetails component - First time onClick it goes inside `componentDidMount` but on click again it's not. That's why  I have `componentDidUpdate` for this. If I remove this `componentDidUpdate`, it always loads the old data in sidebar after onCLick of ID in table.

```
`getDetailsByDeviceID` this is called to get the data from API and sets value in state
```

My Code -

```
    componentWillReceiveProps() {
        this.setState({ sideBarShow: true });
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.getDetailsByDeviceID();
    };

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.deviceId !== prevProps.deviceId) {
            this.getDetailsByDeviceID();
        }
    }
```

getDetailsByDeviceID code -

```
getDetailsByDeviceID = () => {
        try {
            this._getComplianceDetailsApi(); //apis
        } catch (err) {
            toast({
                message: err,
                flavor: "error",
                options: { isHtml: true }
            });
        }
    };
```

If I remove this it calls the page indefinitely.

```
if (this.props.deviceId !== prevProps.deviceId)
```

Do I have to call `componentWillUnmount()`? Please guide me.

Let me know If I am not clear. Thanks.

Comment: My assumption is, `getDetailsByDeviceID` gets data and sets in state. Due to this component is rerendered and in turn will call `componentDidUpdate`. You should look at [shouldComponentUpdate](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/using_should_component_update.html)

Comment: yes rajesh, getDetailsByDeviceID this get the data and set in state, let me check shouldCOmponentUPdate Thanks

Comment: Just a pointer, if you are using latest react, look into `useEffect` hook. That will still do infinite loop but that would be less redundand code

Comment: Yes I have recently updated to react latest version but my code is using old snippets of react version, can you point what I can change and solve this problem if possible.

Comment: Share code for "getDetailsByDeviceID" please.

Comment: Dehan, shared please check, edit my question

Answer (score 1):

If you want your component to re-mount when `deviceId` change you can use the `key` prop on `ComplianceDetails`, like this :

```
<ComplianceDetails key={deviceId} deviceId={deviceId} />
```

Comment: Still the issue remains same, any other solution.

Comment: hi did you get a solution for this issue?