# How to trigger the useCallback in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having a React(version used 16.8) component, I have a `const updateDiffText = useCallback(()` callback on click of anchor `GENERATE DIFF` onclick `onClick={updateDiffText}` I call call back this `updateDiffText`

My requirement is I don't want one anchor code in my UI, I want whenever I have `oldText` and `newText` It should trigger the method `updateDiffText` and show the result. User should not click on anchor link to perform this.

My Code sand box here -  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-diff-view-demo-htp06
if I have values in oldtext and newText it should call updateDiffText this method

My Code -

```
const DiffViewer = props => {
    const oldText = useInput(props.startupConfigData);
    const newText = useInput(props.runningConfigData);
    const [{ type, hunks }, setDiff] = useState("");
    const updateDiffText = useCallback(() => {
        const diffText = formatLines(diffLines(oldText.value, newText.value), {
            context: 3
        });
        const [diff] = parseDiff(diffText, { nearbySequences: "zip" });
        setDiff(diff);
    }, [oldText.value, newText.value, setDiff]);

    const tokens = useMemo(() => tokenize(hunks), [hunks]);

    return (
        <div style={{ height: "450px", overflow: "auto" }}>
            <a href="#" onClick={updateDiffText}>
                GENERATE DIFF
            </a>

            {setDiff ? (
                <Diff
                    viewType="split"
                    diffType={type}
                    hunks={hunks || EMPTY_HUNKS}
                    tokens={tokens}
                >
                    {hunks => hunks.map(hunk => <Hunk key={hunk.content} hunk={hunk} />)}
                </Diff>
            ) : (
                ""
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Let me know if query is not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the useEffect instead of useCallback. In your case you are are not calling the memoized function in the render stage. useCallback will return a memoized function. Check the modified version.

1. https://codesandbox.io/s/react-diff-view-demo-izdyi

Comment: Can you just tell me what `[oldText.value, newText.value],
  setDiff` this is doing in useEffect thanks.

Comment: We don't need the setDiff, it will be ignored by the useEffect. I have removed it now.

Comment: Thanks. I have one query [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58004555/react-componentdidmount-not-called-on-component-reload] do you think useEffect will help me there also.

Comment: I am always having the same value on oldText.value, newText.value inside  useEffect, on click of again it's value is not updating. because useEffect only called once. when component loads. any suggestion ?

Comment: useEffect will be called on every the dependency changes, In your case, it will be called if any of oldText.value or newText.value changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
const updateDiffText = useCallback(() => {
    const diffText = formatLines(diffLines(oldText.value, newText.value), {
        context: 3
    });
    const [diff] = parseDiff(diffText, { nearbySequences: "zip" });
    setDiff(diff);
}, [props.startupConfigData, props.runningConfigData]);
```

to

```
const updateDiffText = useCallback(() => {
    const diffText = formatLines(diffLines(oldText.value, newText.value), {
        context: 3
    });
    const [diff] = parseDiff(diffText, { nearbySequences: "zip" });
    setDiff(diff);
}, [oldText.value, newText.value, setDiff]);
```

////////////// Older solution before i understood ///////////////////////
////////////// New solution i suggest ///////////////////////////////////

```
const updateDiffText = () => {
// do what you wanna do 
}
```

and use useEffect instead of useCallback like this

```
useEffect(() => {
   updateDiffText();
},[props.startupConfigData, props.runningConfigData])
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this doesn't work, I have value of both the props but still it's not going inside this function.

Comment: I think I can help you better if i know what exactly you wanna do and know your code structures

Comment: This is the code sand box I created, https://codesandbox.io/s/react-diff-view-demo-htp06  if I have values in oldtext and newText it should call updateDiffText this method.

Comment: do you get oldtext and newText as props?

Comment: Yes correct, I will get those values from props, I just created sandbox for showing the code. Let me know if it help you to understand.

Comment: why don't you try that new solution

Comment: I changed with this, [https://codesandbox.io/s/react-diff-view-demo-htp06] it looks good, do I need useCallBack as well, It gives one error -    React hook use Effect is missing dependencies

Comment: if you send data properly as props, there will be no errors

Comment: Thanks lukesywaka, This works, both of the answer works. I have one query [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58004555/react-componentdidmount-not-called-on-component-reload] do you think useEffect will help me here also.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html you can see how to replace life cycle methods to useEffect from here

Comment: @lukeskyawaka, I am always having the same value on oldText.value, newText.value inside  useEffect, on click of again it's value is not updating. because useEffect only called once. when component loads. any suggestion ?

Comment: use effect only triggeres when the value of dependencies changes. I think you should think about the structure first

Comment: value is changes onCLick I am passing different props, but still it's not getting called. Any suggestions